# Unable to Update Array object with a new Textinput data in React Native

Tags: javascript, arrays, react-native, react-hooks

I am new to react-native hooks. I am trying to update my array object by whatever the user types in the TextInput field. How can I do it??

where's my state and my folder array object

```
    const [folder, emptyFolder] = useState([]);

      Array [
  Object {
    "id": "0.017859040901406997",
    "value": "Bar",
  },
]
```

where's my TextInput. {itemData.item.value} is where I am displaying the name "Bar".
I want to update my array with a new array TextInput name. That name is whatever the user enters. Thanks In advance.

```
    const handlePress = () => {
       ... { map the array[value] an display the new array[value]} ???
      };

<FlatList
    style={{ margin: 2 }}
    data={folderToDisplay}
    //keyExtractor={(item) => item.id}
    numColumns={4}
    renderItem={(itemData) => {
      return (
        <View style={styles.homeRowFolder}>
          <View style={styles.iconAndText}>
              <Text style={styles.textdisplay}>
                {itemData.item.value}
              </Text>
          </View>
        </View>
      );
    }}
  />
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure what is itemData, I'm supposing is the folder state, in that case I would do something like these.

**UPDATE**

Use setFolder to update your objects Array:

```
  const folderContent = [
    {id: '0.017859040901406997', value: 'Bar'},
    {id: '0.017859040901406998', value: 'Mall'},
    {id: '0.017859040901406999', value: '...'},
    {id: '0.017859040901407000', value: '...'},
  ]
  const [folder, setFolder] = useState(folderContent)
```

Create a folder copy in handlePress function using the new text coming from the TextInput and the array index, and use `setFolder` to save the new array:

```
const handlePress = (text, index) => {
    const newFolder = [...folder]
    newFolder[index].value = text

    setFolder(newFolder)
  }
```

Pass your **folder** as data to your `FlatList`.
In TextInput call `handlePress` when `onChangeText` with the new text and the array index:

```
        <FlatList
          data={folder}
          keyExtractor={item => item.id}
          renderItem={({item, index}) => {
           return (
              <TextInput onChangeText={text => handlePress(text, index)}>
                {item.value}
              </TextInput>
            )
          }}
        />
```

Comment: Hi @Ofito thank you for your response. {itemData.item.value} is how I am getting the value inside the array. I am Not quite sure what you want me to do here const [folder, setFolder] = useState([
    {
      id: '0.017859040901406997',
      value: 'Bar',
    },
  ]). Do you want me to create a new empty state array?? or fill the state with my existence array??? and don't know what is going on here {folder[0].value}. You may notice by now I am lost. Sorry, man, I know you trying to help appreciate you in advance.

Comment: Can you show us where is located TextInput? From where you get `itemData`?

Comment: just update my question hope is more clear now... Thank you in advance for helping me.

Comment: thank you for your help one more question how about if a have more objects in my array? Exemplo {
      id: '0.017859040901406997',
      value: 'Bar',
    },{
      id: '0.017859040901406997',
      value: 'Mall',
    },{
      id: '0.017859040901406997',
      value: '...',
    },{
      id: '0.017859040901406997',
      value: '...',
    }, how can I display the name for each different value?

Comment: Added an update with a `FlatList`. I hope now is more clear.